# How to return back a message after a submit

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code which is not working as expected.  I want to have a retrun from the controller and using alert display the value returned from the controller.

```
 $('#change').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 380,
            buttons: {
                "Close": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                "Accept": function() {
                    var test = $("#ChangePasswordForm").submit();
                    alert(test);
                }
            }
        });
```

In my controller I want to return a string

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public string ChangePassword(string Name)
    {
        var msg = "Cool!";
if (name != null)


return msg;
                }
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller needs to return a type that derives from an ActionResult.

If you want to display a simple confirmation message you can add it to the ViewData bag like this:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult ChangePassword(string name)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            ViewData["msg"] = "Cool";
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Then, in your view, check for the presence of the value, and display it if it's there:

```
<% if(ViewData["msg"] != null) { %>
    <script type="text/javascript">alert('<%= ViewData["msg"].ToString() %>')</script>
<%} %>
```

Comment: That`s quite interesting.  Actually, I need to display the message in the pop up that is already bein displayed. How can I do that?

Comment: In your original code sample, the alert that happens after the submit is modal and is going to block the browser until it is dismissed. You can't append additional content the alert dialog once it is displayed.

Comment: Don'tuse alert - use $('#elementId').html(e.responseText);

Comment: In this approach, if the user do Refresh(Ctrl+F5) then this alert will again fire :(

Answer (score 1):

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
  public ActionResult ChangePassword(string Name)
  {
        var msg = "Cool!";
        if (name != null)
        {       
            return Content(msg, "text/plain");
        }
        else
        {
            return Content("Error...", "text/plain");
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, im assuming you are using an ajax form for this. I also assume you have a  or something for putting your text into. All you have to do is set the UpdateTargetId to point at the id of the element you want to update with the text

```
<%using (Ajax.Form("ChangePasswordForm", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })) %>
```

.

```
[HttpPost]
public ContentResult ChangePassword(string s)
{
      var msg = "Cool!";
      if ( s != null ? return Content(msg, "text/plain") : return Content("An error has occured", "text/plain") );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't submit the form as that will perform a postback and cause the dialog to be removed.

Instead perform an AJAX post to the Controller Action and return a JsonResult containing the data.

Hook into the success callback from the Ajax request, and call alert passing the data from the Json object.

You'll probably wan't to use a loading mask after clicking submit so the user knows something is going on.